# Concerning the fractional part function

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-approximation, fractional-part

I have that $f(x)$ and $g(x,y)$ are real polynomial with no constant terms. We have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ the set

$S_{\epsilon}$ = { $x \in\mathbb{Z} :$ Frac(f(x)) $ < \epsilon $ } is infinite, where Frac(.) is the fractional part function.

Question is whether $T_{\epsilon}$ = { $ (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^{2} : $Frac(g(x,y)) $< \epsilon $ } is infinite $\forall \epsilon > 0$ ?

I tried working with examples : $f(x) = \sqrt{2} x $ and $g(x,y) = \pi xy $ but I couldn't achieve anything. Can anyone help me with this problem, or even the example that I have selected.

**Note** : When all the coefficients of the polynomials are rational, this problem is trivial. Therefore I am taking coefficients $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but for the simple case of $f(x)=x^2$, I get $S_{1/2}=\{0\}$, so clearly finite. The fact that the title and tags talk about "fractional part" also irritates me, as there is no mentioning of it anywhere.

Comment: Fractional part of all integers is zero and hence less than 1/2. ||f(x)|| is the fractional part function. I guess I am gonna edit it to be Frac(f(x)). You have some math help now?

Comment: I see. ||x|| often means the norm of something, so this confused me.

Comment: Generally, for an irrational $\alpha$ the set $\{Frac(\alpha z): z \in \mathbb Z\}$  is dense in $[0,1]$. That means inifinitely many values can be found in any small interval,so also in $[0,\epsilon]$. That shows that your examples $f$ and $g$ have this property. If the functions are more complicated, I need to think more.

Comment: check out weyl polynomial equidistribution theorem which says that if one has a polynomial in one variable with at least one irrational coefficient in degree $1$ or higher, then $P(n)$ is equidistributed modulo $1$ when $n$ runs through the integers or natural numbers; this implies pretty much everything you want as in two variables you can fix one at some integral value st you do not get a nonconstant polynomial and you still have an irrayional coefficient if you start with such

Comment: @Conrad I see.. I think almost all of it makes sense, now that I have acquainted myself with the Weyl's theorem on equidistribution. I am guessing your second last line has a typo. Instead of saying " ... you do not get a nonconstant polynomial .. " you meant to say, " ... you get a non-constant polynomial... "...

Comment: you are right about the typo - the idea is that if you start with a 2 variable polynomial with an irrational coefficient of some nonzero power ($cx^ky^m, k+m >0, c \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$) than you can fix one of the variables at some convenient value (some integer should do it) to get a polynomial to which Weyl's result applies